# List points that fall within a spatial buffer in R

Tags: r, buffer, spatial, points

I am a GIS/Spatial newbie and this might be an easy question.

I have two lists of long/latitudes. The first list will create a buffer of points. I know that it is possible in R to view points and their buffers from a graph. However, is it possible in R to find:

1) How many points from the second list fall within the buffer?

and

2) Which points fall within that buffer?

Note: Suggestions of other common open source software to complete this application would be welcome.

Comment: Once you get your data into `SpatialPolygons*` and `SpatialPoints*` formats, use `sp:over()` or `rgeos:gIntersects()`, as demonstrated in [the answers to this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/63793/5720).

Comment: See also `gBuffer()` and `gWithinDistance()` in the **rgeos** package.

Comment: buffers from the 1st list may overlap? How buffers are defined? a radius in degrees? Could you provide some data?

Comment: [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63793/how-to-overlay-a-polygon-over-spatialpointsdataframe-and-preserving-the-spdf-dat) may be useful.